# send a scenario contains 6 events, x times per hour for y duration in the REST Http web api

Tags: java, angular, multithreading, performance-testing, rest

How to send a scenario contains 6 events, x times per hour for y duration in the REST HTTP web API. This is the current codebase which can support a single scenario. Could someone help me to develop this to accept 19000 scenarios per hour for maximum up to 3 days?

```java
@PostMapping("/sendtest")
public TestResult sendScenario(@RequestBody TestRequest testRequest) throws Exception {
    ExecutorService executor;
    executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
    executor.submit(() - > {
        try {
            this.sendeventfortest(testResult, testRequest.getLoggerURL(), httpEndPoint);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            logger.error("Error occurred while sending scenario with identifier");
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Given you use [PostMapping](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/PostMapping.html) annotation you're using Spring framework to build a web application.
2. Java web applications are launched in the web/application servers like [Jetty](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/) or [Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/) or [JBoss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WildFly) or whatever

So in order to test it you need to deploy your application onto the web or application server and use [a load testing tool like Apache JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/open-source-load-testing-tools-which-one-should-you-use) to conduct the required load and analyze the results.

If your application will be able to handle 19k requests per hour you're good to go, if not - you will need to use [profiler tools](https://www.baeldung.com/java-profilers) to inspect what does your `sendeventfortest` function is doing, where it spends the most time, etc.

Comment: I am building a mockup with front end in angular and the back end in Java to send events to my application written in C#. So the testing input(calls per hour and the test duration) is from the angular to Java through Rest http post request. Can I enhance the rest api to send multiple scenarios(19K) from the java back end rather than using the tools.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the input.

I am building a mockup with front end in angular and the back end in Java to send events to my application written in C#. So the testing input(calls per hour and the test duration) is from the angular to Java through Rest http post request. Can I enhance the rest api to send multiple scenarios(19K) from the java back end rather than using the tools.